# Javascript debugging - Show variables in use

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there any way I can view the variables used in a javascript function without trawling through the code?

Using javascript on a server so cant really install an app to debug, is there a javascript function i can use in some way?

Comment: So, you are not in a web browser? Are you executing this javascript on the command line?

Comment: Do you mean you want to see what variable are used, or their values?  By "using javascript on a server" do you mean the JS is executing on the server, or is the server sending JS to a browser for execution?  (The 2nd is way more common.)

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? In other words, what is it that you think would be useful about "viewing the variables used in a javascript function"?  What sort of bug are you trying to diagnose?

Answer (score 1):

Not unless the JavaScript implementation you're using has some extension that provides such a feature (browsers don't). JavaScript resolves identifiers inside a function using the scope chain; there's no single object that contains all the variables in scope, and the objects in the scope chain are inaccessible from code.